# setuptools python setup.py install not copying all child modules

Tags: python, setuptools

The package dir structure is this

```
repodir/
-------- setup.py
-------- MANIFEST.in

-------- bin/
----------- awsm.sh

-------- sound/
------------ init.py

------------ echo/
----------------- init.py
----------------- module1.py
----------------- module2.py

------------ effects/
------------------- init.py
------------------- module3.py
------------------- module4.py
```

***setup.py***

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
        name = 'sound',
        version = '0.1',
        author = 'awesomeo',
        author_email = 'awesomeo@email.com',
        description = 'awesomeo',
        license = 'Proprietary',
        packages = ['sound'],
        scripts = ['bin/awsm.sh'],
        install_requires = ['Django==1.8.2', 'billiard', 'kombu', 'celery', 'django-celery' ],
        zip_safe = False,
    )
```

When I do - python setup.py install, only sound/**init**.py is copied to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sound/ directory.

The rest of the subpackages echo, surround and effects are not copied at all. Setuptools creates an sound.egg-info which contain SOURCES.txt file

***SOURCES.txt***

```
MANIFEST.in
setup.py
bin/awsm.sh
sound/__init__.py
sound.egg-info/PKG-INFO
sound.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
sound.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
sound.egg-info/not-zip-safe
sound.egg-info/requires.txt
sound.egg-info/top_level.txt
```

Looks like setup does not include the subpackages in the SOURCES.txt file to be copied on install and that is what is creating the problem.

Any idea why this might happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `sound.echo` and `sound.effects` to `packages`. `distutils` won't recursively collect sub-packages.

As per the [fine documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages):

> Distutils will not recursively scan your source tree looking for any directory with an `__init__.py` file

Note: Also be sure to create `__init__.py` files for your packages (In your question you named them `init.py`).

Comment: That worked for me, thanks! Did not know about no recursive scan before.

Comment: You might "accept" the answer if it was helpful .-)

Answer (score 26):

You're already using setuptools so you can import [`find_packages`](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages) to get all sub packages:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    ...
    packages=find_packages(),
    ...
)
```

Comment: Be aware that `find_packages()` will usually pick up tests which is not usually what you want.

Answer (score 0):

#### Set package_dir for package discovery

```py
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    # ...
    package_dir = {'': 'sound'} # folder_name
    # ...
)
```

`package_dir` takes mapping of your packages from where you want your sub-modules or packages to be discovered. Make sure you add `__init__.py` file for your packages.

As per [documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html):

> If your packages are not in the root of the repository or do not correspond exactly to the directory structure, you also need to configure package_dir:

You can have a look around linked documentation for more detailed example.